# It was not possible to find any compatible framework version when trying to scaffold

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core, scaffolding

I am trying to simply follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=netcore-cli) to set up a simple app with authentication.

When I try entering this command

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc WebApp1.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login;Account.Logout"
```

To scaffold a few pages, I get this error

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
>   The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.1.6' was not found.
>     - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>         C:\Program Files\dotnet
>     - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
>         http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
>     - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
>         https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
>     - The following versions are installed:
>         1.0.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         1.0.4 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         1.0.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         1.0.13 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         1.1.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         1.1.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         1.1.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         1.1.10 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         2.0.6 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         2.0.9 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         2.1.0-preview1-26216-03 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         2.1.4 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         2.1.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

I added the nuget package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` as suggested [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9519) but with no effect.

I followed the link to downlowd '.NET core prerequisites`, but this just has the .net sdk...

I have not specified any `2.1.6` anywhere in my project - where would that even be? I also searched the internet for .net core framework 2.1.6 but that doesn't exist..

my csproj file looks like this

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  <UserSecretsId>aspnet-SocFace-D83867AE-294A-4562-B8D7-10674D5B4C05</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="app.db" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.1.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.5" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I tried including a version for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.5"/>
```

but it made no difference

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of your Error Message to make clear what's happening:

> The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', **version '2.1.6' was not found**.
>
> The following versions are **installed**:
>
> 1.0.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>      ...
>   **2.1.5** at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Apparently you've specified the target framework to be version 2.1.6, while the highest version you have installed is 2.1.5. Install version 2.1.6 (or re-target to 2.1.5) and you should be good to go.

**EDIT:**
According to the [Microsoft.NETCore.App page on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.App) version 2.1.6 is a prerelease version. Same for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`. Explicitly setting the versions for your references should solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer rick. I just don't understand though - I hav enot specified anything to use version 2.1.6 anywhere - do you know where I might be able to check that? Searching the entire projecct for `2.1.6` returns nothing. I also searched google for Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 and it doesn't even seem to exist.. Really appreciate any advice you can give as this is driving crazy

Comment: Right click the project in VS and select `Edit <projectname>.csproj`. You should see the `TargetFramework` there.

Comment: I am using VSCode

Comment: I've added my csproj contents to the question